# Checking an array for largest and smallest number

Tags: python

I am trying to check an array for the largest and smallest number.
I have tested multiple times with different numbers and I am getting 9 as my highest value even if I enter a value higher than that. Any thoughts?

```
index = 0
MAX_NUMBERS = 20
numArray = []
stopProgram = 'ZZZ'


for i in range(0, MAX_NUMBERS):
    userNumber = input("Enter a number. 20 numbers total.")
    numArray.append(userNumber)
    index += 1

largeNum = numArray[0]
smallNum = numArray[0]

for i in range(0,MAX_NUMBERS): #Testing for largest and smallest numbers
    if numArray[i] < smallNum:
        smallNum = numArray[i]
    if numArray[i] > largeNum:
        largeNum = numArray[i]


print("Here is your list of numbers: ")
for i in range(0, MAX_NUMBERS):
    print("Numbers entered: " + str(numArray[i]))

print("The largest number was: " + str(largeNum))
print("The smallest number was: " + str(smallNum))
```

Comment: Here is your list of numbers: 
Numbers entered: 7
Numbers entered: 8
Numbers entered: 4
Numbers entered: 6
Numbers entered: 1
Numbers entered: 3
Numbers entered: 5
Numbers entered: 4
Numbers entered: 8
Numbers entered: 6
Numbers entered: 9
Numbers entered: 3
Numbers entered: 4
Numbers entered: 10
Numbers entered: 12
Numbers entered: 13
Numbers entered: 14
Numbers entered: 15
Numbers entered: 16
Numbers entered: 17
The largest number was: 9
The smallest number was: 1

This is how all my outputs end up.

Comment: Because you store strings, not integers.

Answer (score 2):

By default, all input taken by input() function is of <'str'> data type. The int() function converts it from <'str'> to <'int'> before adding it to the list.
Try this:

```
index = 0
MAX_NUMBERS = 20
numArray = []
stopProgram = 'ZZZ'


for i in range(0, MAX_NUMBERS):
    userNumber = int(input("Enter a number. 20 numbers total.")). #wrapped the statement in int() function
    numArray.append(userNumber)
    index += 1

largeNum = numArray[0]
smallNum = numArray[0]

for i in range(0,MAX_NUMBERS): #Testing for largest and smallest numbers
    if numArray[i] < smallNum:
        smallNum = numArray[i]
    if numArray[i] > largeNum:
        largeNum = numArray[i]


print("Here is your list of numbers: ")
for i in range(0, MAX_NUMBERS):
    print("Numbers entered: " + str(numArray[i]))

print("The largest number was: " + str(largeNum))
print("The smallest number was: " + str(smallNum))
```

By the way I would suggest using max and min functions to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) in the python stdlib?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your input with an int so it would be converted to type integer then you can check which number is bigger

I.e

```
yourNumber = int(input("write number"))
```

You can also use the min and Max built in python function which would save you more lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Use `min` & and `max` buildin methods to save you time. Use `string formatting`(f-string) rather than `append` string for efficiency

```
index = 0
MAX_NUMBERS = 20
numArray = []
#stopProgram = 'ZZZ'


for i in range(0, MAX_NUMBERS):
    userNumber = int(input(f"Enter a number. {MAX_NUMBERS} numbers total."))
    numArray.append(userNumber)
    index += 1

#largeNum = numArray[0]
#smallNum = numArray[0]

#for i in range(0,MAX_NUMBERS): #Testing for largest and smallest numbers
#    if numArray[i] < smallNum:
#        smallNum = numArray[i]
#    if numArray[i] > largeNum:
#        largeNum = numArray[i]


print("Here is your list of numbers: ")
for i in range(0, MAX_NUMBERS):
    print("Numbers entered: " + str(numArray[i]))

print(f"The largest number was: {max(numArray)}")
print(f"The smallest number was: {min(numArray)}")
```